# How to use Arrayformula on some of the rows in two ranges

Tags: google-sheets, filter, array-formulas

I'm trying to make some protected sheet which will combine data from two others:

Sheet1 - Has mix of entries:
[image]

Sheet2 - Has only t1 entries
[image]

Sheet3 (protected) - Need `ARRAYFORMULA` for this sheet to be able to make following:
[image]

So in Sheet3 I need to take all t1 entries from Sheet1 and all entries from Sheet2 and list them in Sheet3 ordered by Date.

But so far I could do only `ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A2:C5)` which copies all entries from Sheet1

Comment: A (live) example sheet would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=sort({filter(Sheet1!A2:C5,Sheet1!A2:A5="t1");filter(Sheet2!A2:C5,Sheet2!A2:A5="t1")},3,true)
```

works.

For larger sheets, you should be able to drop the numeral `5` in the above formula.

The `{}` bracket means [local array](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en). `;` means vertical concatenation. For [`sort()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) and [`filter()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en), see official documentation.

Comment: There is no `ARRAYFORMULA` at all in this case, but it works exactly like it. I thought in case of filter we should drag formula, but as I see no. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for QUERY formula:
Try this in Sheet3:

```
=query({Sheet1!A1:C;Sheet2!A1:C},"select * where Col1='t1' order by Col3 asc",1)
```

[image]

Find working example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P6uYZcQJqKt7OVPhYtMoDkssfFbhsJVSGACI8u9qMmo/copy

First:
I combine 2 ranges using { } notation
{range1;range2} means that I stack 2 ranges - one on another.
Then using QUERY i select all the Columns in my combined range and order them by third column.
Number 1 at the end of the formula means that range has one row of headers.

Comment: It works this way also, thanks, I wish I can accept 2 answers